# How to handle this permission error on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs in kotlin/android?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-permissions

Please, consider that I'm new at Kotlin and Android development.

I have an app that users can add a pet with an image. But, when I try to bind the image in the main activity in a `RecyclerView` reading it from SQLite database through ROOM, I always get this permission error below:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{d1c098 21171:com.example.fabicats/u0a183} (pid=21171, uid=10183) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

### Versions and information

- Android Studio Giraffe
- Device emulator API 34
- I've added the image manually using the Device Explorer at the following path `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/image.jpeg` just for testing purposes. I can see the image when the image selector is launched.

### Logical structure

- There is an activity called `PetFormActivity` where the user can choose an image from the device. The image URI is then sent to the database (SQLite + ROOM) within a model to be saved.

```kotlin
class PetFormActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPetFormBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: PetFormViewModel
    private var petId: Int = 0
    private var selectedImageUri: Uri? = null

    private val selectImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        ::onImageSelected // Pass the function reference here
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPetFormBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(PetFormViewModel::class.java)

        // Eventos
        setListeners()

        // Cria observadores
        setObserver()
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (v.id == R.id.button_save) {
            savePet()

        } else if (v.id == R.id.button_choose_image) {
            launchImageSelector()
        }
    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        binding.buttonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun setObserver() {
        viewModel.saveSuccess().observe(this, Observer {
            if (it) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Pet salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Falha ao salvar!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun savePet() {
        var model = PetModel(
            petId,
            binding.editName.text.toString(),
            if (binding.radioButtonMale.isChecked) "male" else "female",
            binding.radioButtonCastrated.isChecked,
            binding.editBirthDate.text.toString(),
            binding.editDeathDate.text.toString(),
            binding.editEyeColor.text.toString(),
            binding.editTemperament.text.toString(),
            binding.editFurColor.text.toString(),
            if (selectedImageUri != null) selectedImageUri.toString() else "",
        )

        viewModel.save(model)
        petId += 1
    }

    private fun launchImageSelector() {
        val intent =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        selectImageLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    // Define a separate function to handle the result
    private fun onImageSelected(result: ActivityResult) {
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            selectedImageUri = data?.data
            binding.imageUploadedPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImageUri)
        }
    }
}
```

- At the `MainActivity` the pet name and image URI are supposed to be shown

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private val adapter = PetsAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        // Layout
        binding.recyclerAllPets.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        // Adapter (needs permission)
        binding.recyclerAllPets.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.getAll()
        setObserver()
        setListener()
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        if (view.id == R.id.fab_add) {
            startActivity(Intent(this, PetFormActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    private fun setListener() {
        binding.fabAdd.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun setObserver() {
        viewModel.pets.observe(this) {
            adapter.updatePets(it)
        }
    }
}
```

- The `PetAdapter` class is responsible for inflating the `RecyclerView` layout that contains just the pet name and pet image, `TextView` and `ImageView` respectively.

```kotlin
class PetsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PetViewHolder>() {

    private var petList: List<PetModel> = listOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PetViewHolder {
        val item = RowPetBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return PetViewHolder(item)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PetViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(petList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return petList.count()
    }

    fun updatePets(list: List<PetModel>) {
        petList = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

- And finally, the `PetViewHolder` binds the name and image from the model to the layout

```kotlin
class PetViewHolder(private val bind: RowPetBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bind.root) {

    fun bind(pet: PetModel) {
        bind.imagePet.setImageURI(Uri.parse(pet.imageURI)) // PROBLEMATIC LINE THAT RAISE THE EXCEPTION
        bind.textPetName.text = pet.name
    }
}
```

### The problem

When I uncomment this line `bind.imagePet.setImageURI(Uri.parse(pet.imageURI))` at `PetViewHolder`, the exception is launched when I start the app.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{d1c098 21171:com.example.fabicats/u0a183} (pid=21171, uid=10183) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

### Attemps

- I've tried to set the runtime permissions using [this official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting), but it didn't work.
- I also added permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, with no success

### Questions

- Is this the best practice for handling images? Saving URI into the database and recovering it?
- Could the image URI be saved into shared storage like in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)?
- [This section](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-access-restrictions) mention restrictions about `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and this is my error. How would I handle this, if its the case?

Comment: Where do you [persist your permission to continue to access the Uri](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions)?

Comment: See also https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: I'm not persistent the permission. Would that be the problem? I'll give it a try!